# How to invoke rotate method in cropperjs

Tags: javascript, crop

Im using cropperjs, i want to create a button to invoke the rotate method in cropperjs, i.e have a button for 90 degrees clockwise and 90 degrees anticlockwise. I tried the code below but didnt work.

```
  <script>
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

            var image = document.getElementById('image');
            var imgRotate = document.getElementById('rotateImg');
            var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                aspectRatio: 20 / 15,

                built: function () {

                }
            });

            document.getElementById('rotateImg').onClick = function () {
                cropper.rotate(90);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: i have added a script. please check the question again

Comment: Nice!  What goes wrong when you use this script?  Is your onClick function firing as expected?  Firing at all? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors. my logs don't even print

Comment: So it sounds like your onClick isn't working as expected.. try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener instead

Comment: Thanks very much, the resource was very useful, it solved my issue. I also found out that the  'onClick' Should rather be 'onclick'

Answer (score 0):

Two steps :

1)
To ensure your function is called, you can trace it as the following.

```
document.getElementById('rotateImg').onClick = function () {
 console.log("I'm in, go to step 2");
  cropper.rotate(90);
 };
```

2)
You need to tell cropper to allow functionnalities you want to use, here is an example with different ones :

```
cropper = new Cropper(image, {
      movable: true,
      zoomable: true,
      rotatable: true,
      scalable: true
    });
```

Hope this will help you to save time.

Comment: thanks very much, buh i have already tried that. i have resolved the issue, please see above comment